# Copying/Pasting Information from Geoprocessing > Results > Messages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I am having difficulty locating the directions for copying and pasting the information in my analysis output to a word document for future reference. Specifically, I would like to highlight and ctrl/C/V the information I attached in the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click "Messages" there should be a copy button that "Copies execution messages into the clipboard for pasting into anything that accepts text, such as a text editor."

Clicking "view" brings up a window within which you can highlight and copy specific lines as you mentioned.